# How to use sed command for deleting few lines

Tags: excel, bash, sed

i have this excel sheet which is generated by appending multiple (here three) other excel sheets.

```
column1,column2,column3
3,4,78
23,56,78
column1,column2,column3
45,23,67
23,98,23
12,34,5
column1,column2,column3
23,67,
23,111,45
```

as you can see these are the combination of 3 similar kind of files. now I want to keep 1st header and want to delete rest of the headers which have come from rest of the i/p files. How can I do this using sed command? thanks.

Comment: Can't you throw away the headers already when concatenating the files?

Comment: yes but only if it doesn't work out. thanks btw :)

Comment: Another awk one-liner, for concatenating the files: `awk 'NR==FNR || (FNR>=2)' file*.csv > joined.csv` It keeps ONE header on joined file & removes other copies of headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this, assuming that the header lines are identical:

```
$ sed '2,${/'"$(head -1 joined.csv)"'/d}' joined.csv 
column1,column2,column3
3,4,78
23,56,78
45,23,67
23,98,23
12,34,5
23,67,
23,111,45
```

Answer (score 2):

an awk one-liner:

```
awk 'NR<2{t=$0}NR<2||t!=$0' file
```

Comment: shorter `awk 't!=$0;!t{t=$0}' file`

Comment: @Jidder Could you explain the `!t{t=$0}`, what is the first `t` for ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu `!t{t=$0}` means do the assignment in `{}` only if `t` is empty

Answer (score 1):

```
sed ':a
$!{N;ba
}
:b
s/^\(.*\n\)\(.*\)\1/\1\2/
tb' YourFile
```

will remove any line identical to the first (so your header here)